# Download queued and stuck

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, downloading

I have Android 5.0.2. A notification showing in Line 1 "Downloading English (US) and Line 2 "Queued". I long touched on it and the text changes to Download Manager. How to get rid of this annoying notification?

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be because of **Google Keyboard** or **Text to speech**.

1. Go to your download manager and **force stop** it.
2. Clear its cache data. (You can do it by going to `Settings -> apps`)
3. Go to Google **Text to speech** from `Language and input -> Text-to-speech-output` and disable `update automatically` from its settings.

In case you didn't find any TTS then do the same with Google Keyboard.

Comment: Your solution is the correct one. I have already done that. I stopped the Google TTS, uninstalled and then reinstalled it. The notification disappeared. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It was Google Photos for me. I do not use Google Photos so I disabled it and it went away.

Otherwise, I am thinking it is waiting for WiFi to download. Connect to WiFi and it will download and install and go away. The burning thing is that it attempts this without permission and I have not found a setting to disable the update in the app without disabling the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's from Google Text to speech

Go to Settings - Apps/App Manager

Check for Google Text to speech app

Navigate to notifications section and turn it off